# PC won't boot unless I leave it connected to power for some time and then turn it on

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

It's a newly assembled PC. Here's my config

- Core i7 7700K
- Asus Strix z270F Motherboard
- Two HDD
- One SSD
- Crosair CX 430 PSU
- GTX 650 Ti Boost
- Cooler Master Liquidlite 120 Cooler

If I shut it down either from an OS or with the power button, it won't turn on, unless I leave it like that for a few minutes. When I press the power button, the PSU turns on, GPU fans work, cooler's light turns on (but the radiator fan doesn't spin), HDDs turn on but the PC doesn't POST or boot. If I long press the power button to turn it off and leave it like that for 5-10 mins, and then try to turn it on, it works. 
I tried disconnecting GPU, all the SATA devices' power etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a power supply problem. I don't think a 430W power supply can adequately power a GTX 650 Ti, which (according to its spec page) requires a minimum system power of 450Ws.

A 7700K also draws a bunch of power, even if you haven't overclocked it. I would recommend upgrading your power supply (or borrowing one from a friend) and see if your system would boot up correctly then.

Comment: Before upgrading the components, I had the same PSU and GPU, but the CPU was a pentium @ 2.6 Ghz. 
If it was the power supply, wouldn't I face random power downs?
I've tortured the CPU after a successful boot and it didn't have any issues. I also checked [here](http://www.coolermaster.com/power-supply-calculator/) and it says I don't require more than 400Ws.
I've tried booting without the GPU and it still has the same issue

Comment: Your symptoms still seems like either the motherboard or the PSU's problem. Try borrowing a PSU from a friend and see if the problem still persists. When something like this happens you usually can use the POST beeps to figure out the problem, but when it doesn't POST at all, it's probably the motherboard (which does the POSTing) or the PSU, which gives the motherboard the power to POST.